# Oracle - creating a group based on group spacing

Tags: oracle, gaps-and-islands

How to make a query that will create groups that have a space between them  greater than "n"?

Data:

```
01-01-2000
02-01-2000
03-01-2000
06-01-2000
07-01-2000
19-02-2001
10-01-2002
11-01-2002
```

I would like to get a result for the interval between records, e.g. 2 days:

```
DATE           GROUP 

    01-01-2000    1
    02-01-2000    1
    03-01-2000    1

    06-01-2000    2    
    07-01-2000    2

    19-02-2001    3

    10-01-2002    4
    11-01-2002    4
```

For 10 days:

```
    01-01-2000    1
    02-01-2000    1
    03-01-2000    1        
    06-01-2000    1    
    07-01-2000    1

    19-02-2001    2

    10-01-2002    3
    11-01-2002    3
```

Another example with integers:

```
with x as (
  select 1 as A from dual
  union all
  select 2 as A from dual
  union all
  select 3 as A from dual
  union all
  select 10 as A from dual
  union all
  select 20 as A from dual
  union all
  select 22 as A from dual
  union all
  select 33 as A from dual
  union all
  select 40 as A from dual
  union all
  select 50 as A from dual
  union all
  select 100 as A from dual
  union all
  select 101 as A from dual
  union all
  select 102 as A from dual
) select A
from x;
```

I need to create groups for a value increase of more than 3:

Example result:

```
1     1
2     1
3     1
10    2
20    3
22    3
33    4
40    5
50    6
100   7
101   7
102   7
```

Comment: Can you post a table structure, which column contains indexes and how many records the tables contains?

Comment: hmm, this is example of table with one column DATE.

Comment: More efficient solutions may be available depending on your Oracle version (for example, using the `match_recognize` clause added in version 12.1). And a couple of questions for clarification: (minor question): when you say "more than 3" do you mean >= 3 or > 3? - based on your first example it seems >, just making sure. (Major question): Are you looking for gaps between consecutive rows? This is easier. Harder: looking for gap from the first row in a group. So, for example, if you are looking for gap > 3 and the numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, are they a single group? Or does 5 start a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( 
  DATE_IN DATE
  );

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (TO_DATE('01-01-2000','DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (TO_DATE('02-01-2000','DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (TO_DATE('03-01-2000','DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (TO_DATE('06-01-2000','DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (TO_DATE('07-01-2000','DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (TO_DATE('19-02-2001','DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (TO_DATE('10-01-2002','DD-MM-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (TO_DATE('11-01-2002','DD-MM-YYYY'));

--HERE IS AN EXAMPLE FOR 1 DAY. Just change the value in the > 1 TO >10 
--if you want to create a group if there is a gap of more than 10days 
SELECT DATE_IN, SUM(NEW_GROUP) OVER ( ORDER BY DATE_IN) AS GROUPE FROM (
  SELECT 
    DATE_IN,
    CASE WHEN DATE_IN - LAG(DATE_IN,1,TO_DATE('01-01-1900','DD-MM-YYYY')) OVER ( ORDER BY DATE_IN) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NEW_GROUP
    FROM TEST
)

-- Result
DATE_IN GROUPE
2000-01-01T00:00:00Z    1
2000-01-02T00:00:00Z    1
2000-01-03T00:00:00Z    1
2000-01-06T00:00:00Z    2
2000-01-07T00:00:00Z    2
2001-02-19T00:00:00Z    3
2002-01-10T00:00:00Z    4
2002-01-11T00:00:00Z    4
```

Comment: yes for this dataset it looks like `DATE_IN - LAG(DATE_IN,1,TO_DATE('01-01-1900','DD-MM-YYYY')) OVER ( ORDER BY DATE_IN) > 1` will not handle ties (two or more records with the same DATE_IN) correctly @TomaszTomzik  same date would cause `DATE_IN - LAG(DATE_IN,1,TO_DATE('01-01-1900','DD-MM-YYYY')) OVER ( ORDER BY DATE_IN) ` into `0`

Comment: It should. Given that there will be less that 1 day between the ties, the difference should be less than 1 so it will not create a new group. lemme check

Comment: I did not know that the SUM (A) OVER (ORDER BY A) would work as a cumulative sum ...

Comment: Yes it works atleast i was right  about the ties [calculation](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59c39/21) what indeed is `0` didn't take the cumulative sum into account..

Answer (score 0):

Example with integer:

```
with x as (
  select 1 as A from dual
  union all
  select 2 as A from dual
  union all
  select 3 as A from dual
  union all
  select 10 as A from dual
  union all
  select 20 as A from dual
  union all
  select 22 as A from dual
  union all
  select 33 as A from dual
  union all
  select 40 as A from dual
  union all
  select 50 as A from dual
  union all
  select 100 as A from dual
  union all
  select 101 as A from dual
  union all
  select 102 as A from dual
) SELECT A, SUM(NEW_GROUP) OVER ( ORDER BY A) AS GROUPE FROM (
  SELECT 
    A,
    CASE WHEN A - LAG(A,1,1) OVER ( ORDER BY A) > 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NEW_GROUP
    FROM X
)
order by A;
```

Comment: Just be carefull with the default value of the LAG for the numbers. If you have negative values or 0, you will have a mistake on your first line. Adapt it to your need or put a very small value as default ( -10000000 )